# tableview edit mode does not allow delete and/or menu: what is missing?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var items = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "mamma mia"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         self.tableView.editing = true
         navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

     func tableView(table1: UITableView,
        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
        -> Int {
            return self.items.count
    }

    // `UITableViewCell`s for each section and row
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
        -> UITableViewCell {
            let item = self.items[indexPath.row]

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel!.text = item
            return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print ("at editing style")
        if editingStyle == .Delete {

            print ("delete at row: \(indexPath.row)")
        }
        if editingStyle == .Insert {
            print ("insert at row: \(indexPath.row)")

        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
//       print ("at can edit row: \(indexPath.row)")

        return true
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    }
}
```

1. why is the menu/delete buttons not appearing?
2. if (when) they do appear, are they processed at commitEditingStyle?

[image: when pressing the button no delete / menu option appears. why ?]

Answer (score 0):

Implement this method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .Delete
}
```

Comment: done that but still no change.  When you press the '-' button the row contents goes blank and no delete /other options appear. using Xcode 7.0 (7A121I)

Comment: OOps. found the problem.

Comment: Sorry: problem was AUTOLAYOUT.  once I fixed the constraints the info appears as desired. Thanks for the help....

Comment: What was it? Please share details :-)

Comment: the constraints were not defined and as a result, the entire cell row was not visible.  I also added another function, which possibly made all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
//            tableView.editing = false
            print("shareAction")
        }
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
//            tableView.editing = false
            print("deleteAction")
        }
 //       shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        return [deleteAction,  shareAction]
    }
```